# On drag and drop in budgie, move the item, not copy

Tags: budgie

On drag and drop budige copies the file. It should be moved. Is there an option or a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Have you tried Shift+Drag or Control+Drag?

Comment: Only Drag from Desktop to Documents copies the item. Only Drag from Documents to Desktop moves the item. Shift+Drag moves the item in both ways. That's so weird.